# URLs of Media Bought on iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, itunes

I have created an application that gets all of the songs on a device, puts some of their information in a UITableView, then plays a song of a selected cell using an AVAudioPlayer. For some reason however, it seems as though three of the songs on my device do not have urls. These songs were more recently bought, perhaps in the last two months. See the code below.

```
//get all the songs
var songsList: [MPMediaItem] = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery().items!

 if let url = song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as! NSURL? {
            self.player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
            let playing: Bool = player.play()
            print("The audio play status: " + String(playing))
        }
        else {
            print("Failed to cast to URL")
        }
```

For some reason, these three songs fail the type cast from AnyObject? to NSURL? meaning that the url must not exist on the device? I do not understand. My only guess is that I bought them from iTunes on another Macintosh device and they were stored on there via some cloud transfer through my iTunes account. Any explanation would be a great help.

Comment: Apple Music tracks maybe?

Comment: @EricD that was my first thought as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get an asset URL if the track is

A) Not on your device -- at least not completely -- but available to download/stream on demand. This can arise by not being completely played; being purchased on other devices/via Family Sharing; being an Apple Match track; yadayadayada.

B) DRM-protected. That's getting pretty rare these days I thought, but it was a big thing back a few years. If the file has an .m4p extension, that is definitely the problem. There's reports that it arises with .m4a files as well, and showing up in iTunes as "Purchased AAC audio file" indicates that it figures you're not allowed to get at said audio.

Comment: the urls are nil for some of the songs. I have mp4a and mp3. If they were mp4s id think they would still show up